# calendar control not showing the number of days in window7

Tags: windows-7, vb6, calendar, controls

I have a VB6 application and am using a calendar control. It is working fine on Windows XP (development machine) but when I try to run it on Windows 7 (32 bit), it is not showing the days and number of date. It shows only a dot (.) in the date columns of the calendar.

I have also checked that `mscal.ocx` and `mscomct2.ocx` are properly registered. I have also checked the fonts that it resides on the system.

Can anyone answer why the calendar control behaves like this, not showing the number date/days?

Answer (score 2):

Try updating your copy of `mscal.ocx` This is a bug in older versions (at least 8.0.0.5007). The latest version available in the VB service packs is 12.0.6413.1000, and over 10 years newer.

Answer (score 0):

When you get the newer version of MSCAL, you have to register it.

Place the newer MSCAL.OCX into C:\windows\System32

Open the Run window (Windows Key + R) 
Enter: regsvr32 C:\windows\System32\Mscal.OCX

You should see a confirmation that it has succeeded.

Your problem should be now resolved, and you may need to restart the OS if no change is noticed.